# Is it possible to drag and drop attachment from Salesforce object to our local desktop

Tags: attachment

We have a requirement to drag and drop a salesforce objects attachment to our local desktop.

i.e to be specific, the user should be able to drag and drop a case attachment to the users local desktop.

I have checked in many sites for feasibility. I could find only requirements for getting files into Salesforce, i need to get my file out of salesforce to my desktop.

Have anyone come across this requirement. If so please let me know the approach.

No idea how to go ahead with this requirement.

referred Links

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HDkXAAW
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000094WqIAI

Thanks and Regards

Venkatesh Kumar S

Comment: I really don't think that it is good idea giving the browser accesss to yur system space however someone has already figured out something like this. I don't know if it works for you but it's worth checking. [Drag Files to desktop Similiar to Gmail](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout). The Idea link you have shared is other way round i.e dropping to Salesfore from desktop.

Comment: Generally speaking, support for this is limited, but all you really need to do is provide a data uri, and your browser will provide the rest. You might look at [this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Recommended_Drag_Types#filestoos) on how it generally works.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very good suggestion to use the following awesome app from Appexchange which can help you do this and many more features like. 
Drag and Drop feature is here to ease the Add Attachment functionality. Now you can Add Attachment to any Object in Salesforce by just a click or dragging and dropping it into your browser window. You can also download multiple attachments. 
Please download the FREE app from this URL.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q6Q1EAI

Comment: I believe the OP is asking other way. I.e. from browser to desktop.